# How do I make the user login the same as the administrator login page?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to use the administrator login page as the standard user login page as well. How do I make this the default login page?

For example, my administrator login at: localhost/administrator/index.php is what I want to display when going to: localhost/index.php?option=com_users

Ideally, when a user is not logged in and they go to localhost, I want to redirect to the administrator login page, and then that page will redirect to the Administrator back-end, or the front-end, depending on their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to create a new template, then set up a menu item for your login page and set your newly created template for that menu item.

If you want to copy the code from the actual login page you can find it here:

```
/administrator/templates/hathor/login.php
```

Remember to update the paths for any dependencies (eg. CSS files etc) or alternatively copy them to your new template directory.